# single.php no wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Se eu tiver um post a minha `single.php` irá exibir esse meu post completo no site. Correto?

Mas se eu tiver também uma página de view de empreendimentos, imóveis, carros, etc... Onde cada uma dessas views tem estilos diferentes, como posso fazer para distinguir isso no wordpress? Por exemplo: A single trataria apenas os posts. Para os empreendimentos por exemplo, seria uma outra view com o mesmo comportamento da single.php, porém não é a single.php!

Conseguiram entender?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quando você trabalha com vários tipos de posts e quer ter um estilo para cada, você pode optar por utilizar os [Custom Post Type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types). Com isso você poderá criar *posts* de vários tipos, com vários outros elementos através de [metaboxes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/). Isso de dará um controle maior sobre o *post* em si.

Apesar de poder customizar esses *posts*, eles ainda se comportarão como qualquer outro *post* do WordPress.

A vantagem é que você consegue gerir melhor esses *posts* personalizados no front-end. Ele também vai te permitir criar páginas "especiais", com características únicas para determinados tipos de *post*.

#### Criando Post Type

Para criar um *post type* personalizado, você poderá utilizar o seguindo código:

```
function create_post_type_car() {
  register_post_type( 'post_car', [
      'labels' => [
        'name' => "Cars",
        'singular_name' => "Car"
      ],
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
    ]
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type_car' );
```

Mais informações sobre a função `register_post_type`, você encontrará na [documentação](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type).

---

#### Exibindo Post Type

Criar um *post_type* é bem simples, mas exibidos é mais simples ainda. Para isso basta cria um arquivo, na raiz do seu tema, chamado `single-post-car.php`. O *WordPress* automaticamente identificará e "linkará" o *post* à essa página.

Isso é possível graças a [Hierarquia de Templates](https://wphierarchy.com/) do *WordPress*.

#### Hierarquia dos Arquivos

No banco de dados, mais especificamente na tabela `wp_posts`, o CMS adicionará todas as informações de arquivos (attachments) enviados e *posts* cadastrados.

Quando o *WP* captura essas informações ele segue uma serie de ações antes de exibi-las, uma dessas ações envolve buscar alguns arquivos na raiz do seu tema e, de acordo com o `mimetype` (arquivos) ou `post type` (postagens), procurar determinado arquivo para servir como `view`.

Nessa busca (no caso de postagens) o *WordPress* retornará o [slug](http://www.ferramentasblog.com/slug-importancia-de-urls-amigaveis-no-blog/) *(ou simplesmente Url Amigavel)* juntamente com outras informações da postagem.

Com essas informações, o *WP* buscará o arquivo `single-$posttype-$slug`, caso não encontre, ele continuará buscando os arquivos necessários até que encontre ou chegue no arquivo "pai", o `index.php`

> A ordem para `Custom Post Types` é: **single-$posttype-$slug.php** -> **single-$posttype.php** -> **single.php** -> **singular.php** -> index.php

---

#### Filtrando Post Type

Você também poderá filtrar determinados tipos de *posts* (Para fazer um menu lateral, por exemplo). Para isso você só precisa utilizar a classe [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). Ex:

```
$posts = new WP_Query([
    "post_type" => "post_car"
]);

if ($posts->have_posts()) {
    while($posts->have_posts()) {
        $posts->the_post();

        the_title();

        /* Code Here */
    }
}
```

---

#### Trabalhando com páginas estáticas no WordPress

Caso você possua apenas páginas estáticas (Sim, elas também "descende" de `single.php`), não é possível utilizar as informações acima como base. Para este tipo de página, o *WordPress* tem uma outra forma de trabalhar.

Estas páginas normalmente são utilizadas para formulários de *contato*, *sobre nós*, *calendário de eventos* etc.

Para cria-las é muito simples, basta criar um arquivo php, exemplo `aboutus.php` e utilizar o código abaixo para servir como `view`.

**Código:**

```
<?php

/* Template Name: AboutUs */

/* Todo o restante do código aqui. Html, css, js; PHP etc */

?>
```

Esse código fará com que apareça uma opção ao adicionar uma nova página estática.

[image: Opção adicionada ao criar um arquivo.php com o comentário "Template Name"]

Dessa forma você poderá trabalhar com várias página de *templates*, com arquivos diferentes, informações diferentes, estilos diferentes, lógicas de negócio diferentes etc.

Comment: Obrigado parceiro. Foi de enorme ajuda. Att, Maurício.